# Apple Watch stuck on Airplay

Tags: security, airplay, apple-watch, airplane-mode

Today I looked at my Apple Watch and I noticed that the airplane mode was turned on. I had not activated it.

When I looked on the glance with the airplane mode button, I noticed that the AirPlay icon was on (lit in blue).  When I tap it, an option comes up for "Apple Watch", but tapping it does nothing but return to the previous screen.

I have been concerned about security issues recently and this was very random.  Is this a bug, and why can't I turn it off?

Answer (score 2):

Usually when that page is stuck, you simply need to power off the watch.

Press and hold the large button (not the crown) and slide to power off. It's slow, so give it a minute or two to shut everything down and then power up the watch.